# DeprecationWarning: sipPyTypeDict() is deprecated PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.11

I was writing the most simplest piece of code to run some small app.

I got the next warning message:

```
~\PycharmProjects\LoggerTest\main.py:10: DeprecationWarning: sipPyTypeDict() is deprecated, the extension module should use sipPyTypeDictRef() instead
  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
```

My code:

```py
# Import libraries
import sys
# from PyQt5 import QtGui
# from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
# from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal #, pyqtSlot
from gui_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    g = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

**What does that warning mean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved in `python-3.12.0`

After upgrading, the warning should be away.

Ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/105747

Comment: doesn't work, after doing ```pyenv versions``` - > ```* 3.12.0 (set by <mypath>)``` still it shows up

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to upgrade your Python version, you can solve the problem by downgrading the PyQt5 module. For my Python 3.7.3 version, I fixed it by downloading PyQt5 version 5.15.4, PyQt5-Qt5 version 5.15.2, and PyQt5-sip version 12.12.1.

Comment: OP asks the *meaning* of the warning, not how to remove it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).