Qt-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets UserWarning: Deprecated imports
I've been testing Qt-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets with both Python 3.9 and Python 3.11 after installing GTK3 to fix the OS Error of the cairo libary not being found, and after running the file, I keep getting this error with either versions:
C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Widgets.py:10: UserWarning: Deprecated imports. For more information, refer to the documentation at: https://github.com/KhamisiKibet/QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\UserPC\OneDrive\Documentos\ProjectSICI\propiedadesmain.py:20: DeprecationWarning: sipPyTypeDict() is deprecated, the extension module should use sipPyTypeDictRef() instead
  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

What should I do to fix this? Here's the code of the python file I've been trying to run through Visual Studio Code:
import os
import sys

import csv
from propiedades import *


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import *
from functools import partial

shadow_elements = { "left_menu","frame_3", "frame_5", "header", "frame_8"}

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            
            self.setMinimumSize(850,600)
            
            loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
            for x in shadow_elements:
                
                effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
                effect.setBlurRadius(18)
                effect.setXOffset(0)
                effect.setYOffset(0)
                effect.setColor(QColor(0,0,0,255))
                getattr(self.ui,x).setGraphicsEffect(effect)
            
            
            self.show()
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



You probably need to use another Python version (possibly upgrading to 3.12) according to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77333277.

@musicamante I did upgraded to Python 3.12.2 but now it won't let me use PyQt5/6 tools, and if I downgraded my python version, then error that I mentioned before will reapper again....
